# How to remove underline in the django endless pagination?

Tags: django, pagination, django-endless-pagination

I have a pagination code like this:

```
 <p> <span>{% get_pages %} {{ pages|length }} pages</span> </p>
        <button class="next_prev" onclick="">{{ pages.first }}</button>
        <button class="next_prev" onclick="">{{ pages.previous }}</button>
        </span> </p>
        <p> <span> <a href="" onclick="css()" id="bgnone" class="bgnone1">{% for page in pages %}
         {{ page|default_if_none:'<span class="endless_separator">...</span>' }}
            {% endfor %}</a></span> </p>
        <button class="next_prev" onclick="">{% get_pages %} {{ pages.next }}</button>

        <button class="next_prev" onclick="">{% get_pages %} {{ pages.last }}</button>
```

It has two flaws:
**One**: The underline is show in page number and in previous and next button which I don't want. 
**Two**: The want to show the symbol `'|<' and '>|'` for first and last page but it shows the page numbers.
Tried using:

```
ENDLESS_PAGINATION_LAST_LABEL in `settings.py` but didn't work.
```

Comment: How to remove the underline from the page number? .bgnone endless_seperator  {text-decoration:none;} didn't work.

Comment: Also the second code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by editing the template 'endless_pagination/templates/endless/page_link.html'

see an example of "page_link.html" it might help.

```
{% if page.is_first %}
{% if page.label != "&lt;" %}

<a href="{{ page.path }}"
   class="endless_page_link" title="first page"><<</a>
<a href="{{ page.path }}"
   class="endless_page_link">{{ page.label|safe }}</a>|
{% else %}
<a href="{{ page.path }}"
   class="endless_page_link" title="previous page">{{ page.label|safe }}</a>
{% endif %}
{% elif page.is_last %}
{% if page.label != "&gt;" %}
<a href="{{ page.path }}"
   class="endless_page_link">{{ page.label|safe }}</a>
<a href="{{ page.path }}"
   class="endless_page_link" title="last page">>></a>
{% else %}
<a href="{{ page.path }}"
   class="endless_page_link" title="next page">{{ page.label|safe }}</a>
{% endif %}
{% elif page.label == "&gt;" %}
<a href="{{ page.path }}"
   rel="{{ querystring_key }}{% if add_nofollow %} nofollow{% endif %}"
   class="endless_page_link" title="previous page">{{ page.label|safe }}</a>
{% elif page.label == "&lt;" %}
<a href="{{ page.path }}"
   rel="{{ querystring_key }}{% if add_nofollow %} nofollow{% endif %}"
   class="endless_page_link">{{ page.label|safe }}</a>
{% else %}
<a href="{{ page.path }}"
   rel="{{ querystring_key }}{% if add_nofollow %} nofollow{% endif %}"
   class="endless_page_link">{{ page.label|safe }}</a>|
{% endif %}
```

Comment: see an example. It might help "page_link.html":